# Use of && and || operators to handle the result of the same command

Tags: bash, shell-script

In bash, is it possible to use these two operators to handle both of the exit statuses of the same command ? or if I want to handle both cases, I have to use an `if` statement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, It's possible

```
[[ "a" == "a" ]] && echo true || echo false
```

Try replacing "a" with "b", to see false:

```
[[ "b" == "a" ]] && echo true || echo false
```

Comment: Yes and no: `[[ "a" == "a" ]] && /bin/false || echo false` gives "false", which may or may not be useful if you just want to look at the exit status of the first command.

Comment: @Ulrich: Dani_l's answer is right.  Your comment is obviously always false since `anything && false` will be false on any system or language.  That's just basic logic.

Comment: in bash , the `&&` operator is not a logical and, it means that it will execute the command found on the right side of the operator, if the left side was executed with success

Comment: The same way, the `||` operator will execute the command on it's right side if the command on it's left side fails.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: yes, which is my point exactly: if the success handler `echo true` should ever fail itself, the failure handler `echo false` is executed, even if the original command was successful.

Comment: @Ulrich: Oh, I see what you mean.  I still think this answer is right but it can be misleading because it doesn't show a separate condition before it echoes.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz How about switching the order? `[[ "a" == "b" ]] || echo false && echo true` ? By that logic I should also echo true since the last operation (`echo false`) succeeded - or am I missing something? `[[ "a" == "b" ]] || /bin/true && echo true` does echo true, but the first example doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest you can get:

```
your_main_command && run_on_success || run_on_failure
```

The caveat is that `run_on_failure` will be run if any of the preceding commands i.e. `you_main_command` or `run_on_success` fails.